# Convert array of ids to array of attributes in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an array of ids: `[111839, 111803, 111774, ...]`. How can I convert it into an array of the value of an attribute of the models corresponding to the ids, e.g `[Jack, John, Sarah, ...]`?

Comment: What is the class? What is the attribute?

Answer (score 1):

```
Person.where(id: array_ids)
```

This gives you a collection of people, if you want just some attributes use pluck and you get an array (array of array in case of more than one attribute)

```
Person.where(id: array_ids).pluck(:name)
```

Comment: Gonna post the same solution. sadly this will not maintain the order

Comment: If you want them ordered you can use `order` method on that. Anyway nobody talk about order.

Comment: You can't use order if the ids are not in order `[10, 5, 7, 3]` now if you want the name of corresponding ids this approach will not help.

Comment: Don't get me wrong I am not fighting over the correctness of answer I am just warning about the possible issues

Comment: I get you. Don't know if here the order matters. In that case maybe is better `pluck(:id, :name)`

Comment: To maintain order... `Person.where(id: array_ids).order("array_position(ARRAY[#{array_ids.join(',')}], people.id)").pluck(:name)`